# Issues with httpd DocumentRoot inside of Vagrant sync folder

Tags: apache, vagrant

I've set up a Vagrant LAMP development environment on my Windows 8.1 machine. The guest operating system is Centos 7. I have a subfolder of my main vagrant folder called workspace which I have synced to /var/www/workspace on my guest. I also have port 80 being forwarded to the guest and httpd running with DocumentRoot of /var/www/workspace. When the folder is empty, I get the standard apache test page. Everything is good so far.

I created an index.html file in the workspace folder on my host machine in SublimeText with the following contents.

```
<html>
Test1
</html>
```

I checked this in the web browser on my host, and get the expected result

```
Test1
```

I continued to edit the index.html file, adding head and body tags and some divs:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="button"><a href="">Test1</a></div>
<div class="button"><a href="">Test2</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I change the text in the links and add a third div.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="button"><a href="">Blog</a></div>
<div class="button"><a href="">Resume</a></div>
<div class="button"><a href="">Experiments</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

As soon as I add the third div, my browser starts returning a previous version of the file with Test1 and Test2 as the link text. I made sure my browser cache was disabled. I checked in the Network section of the Chrome dev console to make sure that the file was coming from the webserver, which it was. I check in vi on the guest machine, and the index file contains the Blog, Resume, Experiments links. If I modify the file in vi by just adding a new line or anything, it fixes the issue. If I remove the third div, it fixes the issue. If I remove the css reference line, it fixes the issue. I have no idea where this old version is or why it's being returned when certain changes are made. My assumption is that it is a vagrant syncing issue, but I'm open to any ideas on what else might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer to my problem although not an ideal one. It appears this is an issue with VirtualBox, not Vagrant. More information about this issue can be found here:

[Ticket 9069](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9069)
[Ticket 819](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/819)

There is no solution, but there is a proposed workaround to avoid this issue. The workaround is to add this to your httpd.conf:

```
EnableSendfile off
EnableMMAP Off
```